# bind event with body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [plugin](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ros2hLL5/).

My problem is the method `itemAdded` is not working on newly added input.

```
$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
     alert('added'); //doesn't work on newly added input
})
```

How to bind it the with body tag?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('itemAdded','input', function(event) {`

Comment: The code necessary to replicate your issue should be **in** the question, not just linked (not even to jsFiddle). External links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. You can include the code in code blocks and link to a fiddle *as well*, or better yet, just use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create a live demo here on site.

Comment: But the fiddle you gave works fine.. I am getting the alerts.. By saying _My problem is the method itemAdded is not working on newly added input._ what does you actually mean?